# Finding index of positivity

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on this Linear Algebra problem:

> Compute the index of positivity of $f(X) = -x_1^2 - x_1x_2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2$.

Here are what I have "mechanically" done so far:

$$\begin{align}
f(X) &= -x_1^2 - x_1x_2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2\\
&= \frac{1}{4}x_1^2 - \frac{5}{4}x_1^2- x_1x_2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2\\
&= (\frac{1}{2}x_1 - x_2)^2 - \frac{5}{4}x^2_1 + x_3^2.
\end{align}$$

Because the first and the last term will always be positive, therefore the index is 2. But beyond the above lines, unfortunately I really do not understand what does it mean by the index of positivity, and why the count of positive term is the index. Any explanation in plain simple English would be very much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of positivity counts the number of independent directions in which a function increases at a critical point—the origin in this case. There’s a pretty good [Wikipedia gloss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory) on this.

It’s easiest to get a feel for what’s going on in three dimensions. Consider the three functions $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, $G(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and $H(x,y)=-x^2-y^2$, which all have a critical point at the origin. $F$ has a maximum, increasing in all directions, so it certainly increases in any two of them. Its index is therefore $2$. Similarly, the index of $H$ is $0$ since it decreases in every direction from the origin. $G$ has a saddle point at the origin, increasing along the $x$-axis and decreasing along the $y$-axis: its index is thus $1$. Observe that these expressions have no cross terms $x_ix_j$ $(i\ne j)$, so we can just count the number of $+$ signs to find the index.

It turns out that for quadratic forms, of which all of these functions are examples, it’s always possible to find a rotation that eliminates all of the cross terms. This is basically what you’ve done with your “mechanical” manipulations. The axes of this new coordinate system are known as the *principal axes* of the quadratic form. The sign of each of the remaining squared terms tells you whether the function increases or decreases in that direction.

Comment: Thank you for your pretty good explanation.